# block parent jquery functions when calling child function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with conflicting parent/child jquery functions. The child function is a bootstrap function, the parent is a custom function. The idea is that the parent div (see code below) can contain too much data, and thus should be limited in height. there is a toggle when you click in the div, to expand it, but that should not happen when i click on a child element, because this one also collapses down.

```
<div id="items" class="semiCollapsed">
  <span data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#x" > an item</span>
  <div id="x" class="collapse">description of item</div>
  ... more items ...
</div>
```

The function for my parrent JQuery is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#items').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#items").toggleClass("semiCollapsed");
  })
});
```

and the css:

```
.semiCollapsed {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-height:110px;
}
```

Bootstrap Collapse:

http://pastebin.com/Xfnq7R4i

The problem I'm having is that the parent get called when i call the child function. How to fix this?

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7fdjL3qx/

Comment: Why do you use JQuery to achieve something so simple? You can do the same thing in plain javascript without effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If clicked item is not target we must return.   `if (event.target !== this) return;`

```
    jQuery('#items').on('click', function (event) {
        if (event.target !== this) return;
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("semiCollapsed");
    });
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/abhiklpm/7fdjL3qx/1/

Answer (score 1):

use `event.stopPropagation();` instead of `event.preventDefault();`.

Because events happening on child bubbles up to the parents so all the events bound on parents also gets executed.

So to stop the event to bubble up to the parent you need to have `event.stopPropagation()` on child click events.

Comment: This has the opposite effect: The parent still works when clicked on the child, but not the child.

Comment: @pidgey where is your child click event? is this above posted in the question? or any other?

Comment: Apologies, my posted code was partially wrong. I edited it. The child is within the parent

Comment: Note:  _to stop the event to bubble up to the parent you need to have event.stopPropagation() on child click events._ the last line i have written. stop propagation has to be used on child clicked events.

Comment: But the child is default bootstrap. Can I override that without changing the bootstrap code?

Comment: @pidgey can you post the function in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use check `event.target.id` inside click element and if it is `items` then only toggle class.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#items').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(event.target.id=="items")
   {
    //use this for clicked element instead of finding it again using id
    $(this).toggleClass("semiCollapsed");
   }
  });
});
```

Comment: This has the opposite effect: The parent still works when clicked on the child, but not the child.

Comment: I cannot find any element with `id="vuln-conf"` in you html shared. is `vuln-conf` is parent and child is something else?

Comment: Oh, right, i made the code a bit more generic for stackoverflow, let me edit it... Sorry

Comment: The problem is that (my interpretation of the result) the child element is concidered part of the parent, as it's just text...

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement

Comment: Done. Not sure why the bootstrap collapse stopped working tho, I imported the file ...

Comment: You missed the `#` in this `data-target="#a"`